# Copying HTML code in Google Chrome's inspect element

Tags: html, google-chrome, copy, google-chrome-devtools, inspect-element

I have a website of which I want to copy an HTML code from - **how do I copy all the text in inspect element** - so I don't get the website's HTML code, but the code that I have already changed so that I don't have elements I don't want in my own webpage?

Comment: Right click on `<html>`, "Copy as HTML"?

Comment: Thank you, should have figured it out. Fastest answer ever...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Dev Tools export Elements HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151446/chrome-dev-tools-export-elements-html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying Code from Inspect Element in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576247/copying-code-from-inspect-element-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 123):

Do the following:

1. Select the top most element, you want to copy. (To copy all, select `<html>`)
2. Right click.
3. Select Edit as HTML
4. New sub-window opens up with the HTML text.
5. This is your chance. Press CTRL+A/CTRL+C and copy the entire text field to a different window.

it's the easiest way to do this.

Comment: I've slightly edited your answer to use Markdown formatting instead of manual stuff. I'd recommend learning Markdown, if only because your posts become so much prettier :)

Comment: It copies all page elements but it does not copy inputted values. How can I copy the page source and the input values together? @barryjones

Answer (score 23):

1. Right click → copy → copy element

[image]

Comment: It copies all page elements but it does not copy inputted values. How can I copy the page source and the input values together?

Answer (score 8):

1. Select the `<html>` tag in Elements.
2. Do CTRL-C.
3. Check if there is only lefting `<!DOCTYPE html>` before the `<html>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTTrack software you can download all the website content to your local directory.
HTTrack: http://www.httrack.com/

Comment: This is the more correct answer. Copy element copies the source of the page and not the rendered content :(

Answer (score 0):

**This is bit tricky**

Now a days most of website new techniques to save websites from scraping

> **1st Technique**

**Ctrl+U**         this will show you Page Source
[image]

> **2nd Technique**

This one is small hack if the website has ajax like functionality.

**Just Hover the mouse key on inspect element untill whole screen becomes just right click then and copy element**
[image]

> That's it you are good to go.