# How can I copy all text in Chrome's "Elements" inspector?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, webkit, google-chrome-devtools, inspector

I would like to copy **all** of the **expanded** code found in the "Elements" pane of Google Chrome's WebKit inspector to my clipboard. I'm on OS X.

Here is a screenshot of this pane (on the left side of the screen):

[image]

It appears that I am only able to select individual lines or sections, but not the entire text.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question. The solution is mentioned obliquely in parentheses in step one of the following answer:

- [*Stack Overflow - Copying HTML code in Google Chrome's inspect element*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343191/copying-html-code-in-google-chromes-inspect-element/34365058#34365058)

You have to right-click the topmost `<html>` element, and then click <kbd>**Edit** as HTML</kbd>.

The full code will now exist in a standard, editable text field, where you can finally <kbd>Select All</kbd> and <kbd>Copy</kbd> the text contents to the clipboard.

Comment: This doesn't always work.  Take the case of the Chrome Downloads history.  If you use this method to capture the HTML of the downloads history, you'll basically get a load of styling and no actual links.