# How to copy all CSS code in Google Chrome's inspect element?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I copied the HTML element referring to the following article.
[Copying HTML code in Google Chrome's inspect element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343191/copying-html-code-in-google-chromes-inspect-element)

But I couldn't copy the css for each class.

How do I copy all the css like the method in the post above?

Right now, I am applying copy styles by clicking on one tag one by one, but I don't think this is a awesome way.

I want to copy all the css.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can get focus in the `Styles` pane, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy as usual.

I find it's easiest to click in the bottom-right corner of one of the listed styles to avoid giving focus to a rule in the style (which would prevent you from selecting more than that rule). See the red circle in the picture below to see where I normally click. Admittedly it will usually take a few attempts; just keep trying to select all and adjusting where you click until it works.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

```
element.style {
}
.question {
    clear: both;
}

body *, body *:before, body *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
body.theme-dark, body.theme-dark__forced {
    --subcommunity-audiobubble-color: #d64a17;
    --subcommunity-google-cloud-color: #ffffff;
    --subcommunity-go-color: #5DC9E2;
}
body.theme-dark, body:not(.theme-dark) .theme-dark__forced, body.theme-dark .themed, body:not(.theme-dark) .theme-dark__forced .themed {
    --theme-primary-color-h: var(--theme-dark-primary-color-h, var(--theme-base-primary-color-h));
    --theme-primary-color-s: var(--theme-dark-primary-color-s, var(--theme-base-primary-color-s));
    --theme-primary-color-l: var(--theme-dark-primary-color-l, var(--theme-base-primary-color-l));
    --theme-primary-color-r: var(--theme-dark-primary-color-r, var(--theme-base-primary-color-r));
    --theme-primary-color-g: var(--theme-dark-primary-color-g, var(--theme-base-primary-color-g));
    --theme-primary-color-b: var(--theme-dark-primary-color-b, var(--theme-base-primary-color-b));
    --theme-secondary-color-h: var(--theme-dark-secondary-color-h, var(--theme-base-secondary-color-h));
    --theme-secondary-color-s: var(--theme-dark-secondary-color-s, var(--theme-base-secondary-color-s));
    --theme-secondary-color-l: var(--theme-dark-secondary-color-l, var(--theme-base-secondary-color-l));
    --theme-secondary-color-r: var(--theme-dark-secondary-color-r, var(--theme-base-secondary-color-r));
    --theme-secondary-color-g: var(--theme-dark-secondary-color-g, var(--theme-base-secondary-color-g));
    --theme-secondary-color-b: var(--theme-dark-secondary-color-b, var(--theme-base-secondary-color-b));
    --theme-primary-color: hsl(var(--theme-primary-color-h), var(--theme-primary-color-s), var(--theme-primary-color-l));
    --theme-secondary-color: hsl(var(--theme-secondary-color-h), var(--theme-secondary-color-s), var(--theme-secondary-color-l));
    --theme-primary-025: hsl(var(--theme-primary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-s) - 82%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-l) - 17%), 100%));
    --theme-primary-050: hsl(var(--theme-primary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-s) - 47%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-l) - 15%), 100%));
    --theme-primary-075: hsl(var(--theme-primary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-s) - 39%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-l) - 13%), 100%));
    --theme-primary-100: hsl(var(--theme-primary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-s) - 32%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-l) - 11%), 100%));
    --theme-primary-150: hsl(var(--theme-primary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-s) - 23%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-l) - 9%), 100%));
    --theme-primary-200: hsl(var(--theme-primary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-s) - 15%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-l) - 7%), 100%));
    --theme-primary-300: hsl(var(--theme-primary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-s) - 7%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-primary-color-l) - 5%), 100%));
    --theme-primary-350: var(--theme-primary-color);
    --theme-primary-400: rgb(calc(53.55 + var(--theme-primary-color-r) * .79), calc(53.55 + var(--theme-primary-color-g) * .79), calc(53.55 + var(--theme-primary-color-b) * .79));
    --theme-primary-500: rgb(calc(91.8 + var(--theme-primary-color-r) * .64), calc(91.8 + var(--theme-primary-color-g) * .64), calc(91.8 + var(--theme-primary-color-b) * .64));
    --theme-primary-600: rgb(calc(130.05 + var(--theme-primary-color-r) * .49), calc(130.05 + var(--theme-primary-color-g) * .49), calc(130.05 + var(--theme-primary-color-b) * .49));
    --theme-primary-700: rgb(calc(168.3 + var(--theme-primary-color-r) * .34), calc(168.3 + var(--theme-primary-color-g) * .34), calc(168.3 + var(--theme-primary-color-b) * .34));
    --theme-primary-800: rgb(calc(206.55 + var(--theme-primary-color-r) * .19), calc(206.55 + var(--theme-primary-color-g) * .19), calc(206.55 + var(--theme-primary-color-b) * .19));
    --theme-primary-900: rgb(calc(244.8 + var(--theme-primary-color-r) * .04), calc(244.8 + var(--theme-primary-color-g) * .04), calc(244.8 + var(--theme-primary-color-b) * .04));
    --theme-secondary-025: hsl(var(--theme-secondary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-s) - 82%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-l) - 17%), 100%));
    --theme-secondary-050: hsl(var(--theme-secondary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-s) - 47%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-l) - 15%), 100%));
    --theme-secondary-075: hsl(var(--theme-secondary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-s) - 39%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-l) - 13%), 100%));
    --theme-secondary-100: hsl(var(--theme-secondary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-s) - 32%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-l) - 11%), 100%));
    --theme-secondary-150: hsl(var(--theme-secondary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-s) - 23%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-l) - 9%), 100%));
    --theme-secondary-200: hsl(var(--theme-secondary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-s) - 15%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-l) - 7%), 100%));
    --theme-secondary-300: hsl(var(--theme-secondary-color-h), clamp(10%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-s) - 7%), 90%), clamp(20%, calc(var(--theme-secondary-color-l) - 5%), 100%));
    --theme-secondary-350: var(--theme-secondary-color);
    --theme-secondary-400: rgb(calc(53.55 + var(--theme-secondary-color-r) * .79), calc(53.55 + var(--theme-secondary-color-g) * .79), calc(53.55 + var(--theme-secondary-color-b) * .79));
    --theme-secondary-500: rgb(calc(91.8 + var(--theme-secondary-color-r) * .64), calc(91.8 + var(--theme-secondary-color-g) * .64), calc(91.8 + var(--theme-secondary-color-b) * .64));
    --theme-secondary-600: rgb(calc(130.05 + var(--theme-secondary-color-r) * .49), calc(130.05 + var(--theme-secondary-color-g) * .49), calc(130.05 + var(--theme-secondary-color-b) * .49));
    --theme-secondary-700: rgb(calc(168.3 + var(--theme-secondary-color-r) * .34), calc(168.3 + var(--theme-secondary-color-g) * .34), calc(168.3 + var(--theme-secondary-color-b) * .34));
    --theme-secondary-800: rgb(calc(206.55 + var(--theme-secondary-color-r) * .19), calc(206.55 + var(--theme-secondary-color-g) * .19), calc(206.55 + var(--theme-secondary-color-b) * .19));
    --theme-secondary-900: rgb(calc(244.8 + var(--theme-secondary-color-r) * .04), calc(244.8 + var(--theme-secondary-color-g) * .04), calc(244.8 + var(--theme-secondary-color-b) * .04));
    --focus-ring: hsla(var(--theme-secondary-color-h), var(--theme-secondary-color-s), var(--theme-secondary-color-l), .25);
    --theme-body-font-color: var(--black-800);
}
body.theme-dark, body:not(.theme-dark) .theme-dark__forced {
    --white: #2d2d2d;
    --black: #fff;
    --black-025: #393939;
    --black-050: #3d3d3d;
    --black-075: #404345;
    --black-100: #4a4e51;
    --black-150: #555a5e;
    --black-200: #697075;
    --black-300: #7d848d;
    --black-350: #959ca3;
    --black-400: #9fa6ad;
    --black-500: #acb2b8;
    --black-600: #c4c8cc;
    --black-700: #cfd2d6;
    --black-750: #dadee0;
    --black-800: #e7e8eb;
    --black-900: #f2f2f3;
    --orange-050: #473c33;
    --orange-100: #5e4433;
    --orange-200: #8d5a2f;
    --orange-300: #cc7525;
    --orange-400: #f48024;
    --orange-500: #ff901e;
    --orange-600: #ffa95e;
    --orange-700: #f8b682;
    --orange-800: #fcd6b9;
    --orange-900: #fee7d6;
    --blue-050: #233e52;
    --blue-100: #25445f;
    --blue-200: #295070;
    --blue-300: #2b5f8a;
    --blue-400: #3070ab;
    --blue-500: #378ad3;
    --blue-600: #3ca4ff;
    --blue-700: #81c4f8;
    --blue-800: #b8dffd;
    --blue-900: #d5ecfd;
    --powder-050: #414648;
    --powder-100: #3e4a52;
    --powder-200: #43525f;
    --powder-300: #4c6071;
    --powder-400: #577489;
    --powder-500: #688eac;
    --powder-600: #7badd3;
    --powder-700: #9cc3db;
    --powder-800: #cde1ee;
    --powder-900: #e5f3ff;
    --green-025: #2e4233;
    --green-050: #344b3a;
    --green-100: #3d6048;
Show All Properties (60 more)
}
body {
    --subcommunity-audiobubble-color: #29b5e8;
    --subcommunity-google-cloud-color: #3367D6;
    --subcommunity-go-color: #253443;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: var(--theme-background-color);
    background-image: none;
    background-position: var(--theme-background-position);
    background-repeat: var(--theme-background-repeat);
    background-size: var(--theme-background-size);
    background-attachment: var(--theme-background-attachment);
    min-width: 1279px;
    --mp-alt-row-color: var(--black-050);
    --mp-critical-color: var(--red-600);
    --mp-duration-color: var(--black-800);
    --mp-gap-bg-color: var(--black-025);
    --mp-gap-font-color: var(--black-700);
    --mp-highlight-default-color: var(--fc-dark);
    --mp-highlight-fade-color: var(--yellow-300);
    --mp-highlight-keyword-color: var(--blue-700);
    --mp-highlight-literal-color: var(--green-500);
    --mp-label-color: var(--black-700);
    --mp-link-color: var(--blue-700);
    --mp-main-bg-color: var(--white);
    --mp-muted-color: var(--black-300);
    --mp-popup-shadow: var(--bs-sm);
    --mp-query-border-color: var(--black-100);
    --mp-result-border: solid .5px var(--black-300);
    --mp-warning-color: var(--red-600);
}
html, body {
    color: var(--theme-body-font-color);
    font-family: var(--theme-body-font-family);
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.30769231;
}
body {
    --theme-base-primary-color-h: 26.53846154;
    --theme-base-primary-color-s: 90.43478261%;
    --theme-base-primary-color-l: 54.90196078%;
    --theme-base-primary-color-r: 244;
    --theme-base-primary-color-g: 128;
    --theme-base-primary-color-b: 36;
    --network-theme-primary-color-h: 26.53846154;
    --network-theme-primary-color-s: 90.43478261%;
    --network-theme-primary-color-l: 54.90196078%;
    --network-theme-primary-color-r: 244;
    --network-theme-primary-color-g: 128;
    --network-theme-primary-color-b: 36;
    --network-theme-primary-color: hsl(var(--network-theme-primary-color-h), var(--network-theme-primary-color-s), var(--network-theme-primary-color-l));
    --network-theme-primary-color-darken-5: hsl(var(--network-theme-primary-color-h), var(--network-theme-primary-color-s), calc(var(--network-theme-primary-color-l) - 5%));
    --network-theme-primary-color-darken-10: hsl(var(--network-theme-primary-color-h), var(--network-theme-primary-color-s), calc(var(--network-theme-primary-color-l) - 10%));
    --network-theme-primary-color-darken-15: hsl(var(--network-theme-primary-color-h), var(--network-theme-primary-color-s), calc(var(--network-theme-primary-color-l) - 15%));
    --network-theme-primary-color-darken-20: hsl(var(--network-theme-primary-color-h), var(--network-theme-primary-color-s), calc(var(--network-theme-primary-color-l) - 20%));
    --network-theme-primary-color-darken-30: hsl(var(--network-theme-primary-color-h), var(--network-theme-primary-color-s), calc(var(--network-theme-primary-color-l) - 30%));
    --network-theme-primary-color-lighten-10: hsl(var(--network-theme-primary-color-h), var(--network-theme-primary-color-s), calc(var(--network-theme-primary-color-l) + 10%));
    --network-theme-primary-color-tint-10: rgb(calc(25.5 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-r) * .9), calc(25.5 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-g) * .9), calc(25.5 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-b) * .9));
    --network-theme-primary-color-tint-50: rgb(calc(127.5 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-r) * .5), calc(127.5 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-g) * .5), calc(127.5 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-b) * .5));
    --network-theme-primary-color-tint-60: rgb(calc(153 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-r) * .4), calc(153 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-g) * .4), calc(153 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-b) * .4));
    --network-theme-primary-color-tint-70: rgb(calc(178.5 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-r) * .3), calc(178.5 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-g) * .3), calc(178.5 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-b) * .3));
    --network-theme-primary-color-tint-80: rgb(calc(204 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-r) * .2), calc(204 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-g) * .2), calc(204 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-b) * .2));
    --network-theme-primary-color-tint-85: rgb(calc(216.75 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-r) * .15), calc(216.75 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-g) * .15), calc(216.75 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-b) * .15));
    --network-theme-primary-color-tint-90: rgb(calc(229.5 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-r) * .1), calc(229.5 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-g) * .1), calc(229.5 + var(--network-theme-primary-color-b) * .1));
    --network-theme-primary-color-fade-5: hsla(var(--network-theme-primary-color-h), var(--network-theme-primary-color-s), var(--network-theme-primary-color-l), .05);
    --network-theme-primary-color-fade-50: hsla(var(--network-theme-primary-color-h), var(--network-theme-primary-color-s), var(--network-theme-primary-color-l), .5);
    --network-theme-primary-color-fade-75: hsla(var(--network-theme-primary-color-h), var(--network-theme-primary-color-s), var(--network-theme-primary-color-l), .75);
    --network-theme-primary-color-fade-80: hsla(var(--network-theme-primary-color-h), var(--network-theme-primary-color-s), var(--network-theme-primary-color-l), .8);
    --theme-button-color: var(--blue-600);
    --theme-button-hover-color: var(--blue-700);
    --theme-button-hover-background-color: var(--blue-050);
    --theme-button-active-background-color: var(--blue-100);
    --theme-button-selected-color: var(--blue-900);
    --theme-button-selected-background-color: var(--blue-200);
    --theme-button-filled-color: var(--powder-700);
    --theme-button-filled-background-color: var(--powder-100);
    --theme-button-filled-border-color: var(--powder-500);
    --theme-button-filled-hover-color: var(--powder-800);
    --theme-button-filled-hover-background-color: var(--powder-300);
    --theme-button-filled-active-background-color: var(--powder-400);
    --theme-button-filled-active-border-color: var(--powder-600);
    --theme-button-filled-selected-color: var(--powder-900);
    --theme-button-filled-selected-background-color: var(--powder-500);
    --theme-button-filled-selected-border-color: var(--powder-700);
    --theme-button-outlined-border-color: var(--blue-400);
    --theme-button-outlined-selected-border-color: var(--blue-600);
    --theme-button-primary-background-color: var(--blue-500);
    --theme-button-primary-hover-background-color: var(--blue-600);
Show All Properties (52 more)
}
body {
    --ff-sans: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Liberation Sans",sans-serif;
    --ff-serif: Georgia,Cambria,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    --ff-mono: ui-monospace,"Cascadia Mono","Segoe UI Mono","Liberation Mono",Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,monospace;
    --theme-body-font-family: var(--ff-sans);
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
html.html__fixed-top-bar {
    --top-bar-allocated-space: 50px;
}
:root {
    --theme-base-primary-color-h: 26.53846154;
    --theme-base-primary-color-s: 90.43478261%;
    --theme-base-primary-color-l: 54.90196078%;
    --theme-base-primary-color-r: 244;
    --theme-base-primary-color-g: 128;
    --theme-base-primary-color-b: 36;
    --theme-base-secondary-color-h: 205;
    --theme-base-secondary-color-s: 100%;
    --theme-base-secondary-color-l: 40%;
    --theme-base-secondary-color-r: 0;
    --theme-base-secondary-color-g: 119;
    --theme-base-secondary-color-b: 204;
}
html {
    --top-bar-allocated-space: 0px;
}
body *, body *:before, body *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body *, body *:before, body *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```